# Cannot locally browse to index.html when running API project in Docker container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to set up my .NET API to run in a Docker container and be accessible via my browser. I'm having trouble when running for local development. The repo (on the dev branch specifically) is [here](https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet/tree/dev).

My API was previously set up to run alongside a UI project, which ran by default when I started the application, but I'm working on removing that (you can see that commented out in the csproj file for the API [here](https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet/blob/9c3d31f1b7b7b52db00b972a175e3430df4c0f54/rardk.web/rardk.web.API/rardk.web.API.csproj#L29)). I've added a wwwroot to the `rardk.web.API` project, and I've unloaded the `rardk.web.UI` project, but I don't seem to get my test HTML page when running the API project as the startup project.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["rardk.web.UI/nuget.config", "rardk.web.UI/"]
COPY ["rardk.web.API/rardk.web.API.csproj", "rardk.web.API/"]
COPY ["rardk.web.BusinessLayer/rardk.web.BusinessLayer.csproj", "rardk.web.BusinessLayer/"]
COPY ["rardk.web.ServiceLayer/rardk.web.ServiceLayer.csproj", "rardk.web.ServiceLayer/"]
COPY ["rardk.web.Models/rardk.web.Models.csproj", "rardk.web.Models/"]
# COPY ["rardk.web.UI/rardk.web.UI.esproj", "rardk.web.UI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./rardk.web.API/./rardk.web.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/rardk.web.API"
RUN dotnet build "./rardk.web.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./rardk.web.API.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "rardk.web.API.dll"]
```

and my launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5227"
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7042;http://localhost:5227"
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS": "8081",
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS": "8080"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:36857",
      "sslPort": 44319
    }
  }
}
```

These are the logs in my container, including the 404s when I tried to browse to it:

```
2024-01-07 11:44:56 [16:44:56 INF] Now listening on: http://[::]:8080
2024-01-07 11:44:56 [16:44:56 INF] Now listening on: https://[::]:8081
2024-01-07 11:44:56 [16:44:56 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2024-01-07 11:44:56 [16:44:56 INF] Hosting environment: Development
2024-01-07 11:44:56 [16:44:56 INF] Content root path: /app
2024-01-07 11:45:09 [16:45:09 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:32771/ - null null
2024-01-07 11:45:10 [16:45:10 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:32771/ - 307 0 null 130.1059ms
2024-01-07 11:45:10 [16:45:10 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:32770/ - null null
2024-01-07 11:45:10 [16:45:10 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:32770/index.html - 404 0 null 69.0943ms
2024-01-07 11:45:10 [16:45:10 INF] Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code. Request path: GET https://localhost:32770/index.html, Response status code: 404
2024-01-07 11:45:50 [16:45:50 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:32771/ - null null
2024-01-07 11:45:50 [16:45:50 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:32771/ - 307 0 null 1.7569ms
2024-01-07 11:45:50 [16:45:50 INF] Request starting HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:32770/ - null null
2024-01-07 11:45:50 [16:45:50 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 GET https://localhost:32770/index.html - 404 0 null 84.2565ms
2024-01-07 11:45:50 [16:45:50 INF] Request reached the end of the middleware pipeline without being handled by application code. Request path: GET https://localhost:32770/index.html, Response status code: 404
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running the docker container in the development mode (from the logs):

> 2024-01-07 11:44:56 [16:44:56 INF] Hosting environment: Development

But you are serving static files only for non-development environments:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // <- here
}
```

So the `index.html` from `wwwwroot` will not be served in the Development one. Just remove the else and add static files unconditionally:

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: That did it! Such a simple oversight, thank you!